# Count Multi-level marketing (tree) record in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

users table

[image]

In the Registration time every user have to put parent_id , who registration under parent_id, so i made different table for it

sponser table

[image]

after that make tree like that

[image]

and i want to count record like that

[image]

so plz guide me how can i count record like that or there is any way i mean to say for this kind of counting i have to change in database , thanks in advance

Comment: how did you made the tree structure output like the [image above](http://i.stack.imgur.com/p4XdG.gif) ??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i have Adjacency model structure in table, so i got it very nice solution count user_id under parent_id

**that function count user_id under parent_id**

```
function display_children($parent, $level) {
    $count = 0;
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT user_id FROM sponsers '.'WHERE parent_id="'.$parent.'"');
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
           $var = str_repeat(' ',$level).$row['user_id']."\n";

                   //echo $var  after remove comment check tree

                   // i call function in while loop until count all user_id 

           $count += 1 +$this->display_children($row['user_id'], $level+1);

    }
    return $count; // it will return all user_id count under parent_id
}
```

**call function**

```
display_children(999, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess, that you are searching for this http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/.

It is called `TREE TRAVERSAL`. Well in your case  you can use it just for counting.
More information on that topic can be found here [Tree data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_data_structure)

Answer (score 0):

for hierarchical data storing you can see `Nested Set Model`. see in detail http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model.
hope it will perfectly serve your purpose.